# how to loop trough arrays in json data using only javscript

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

Data source (JSON):

```
{
  "photographers": [{
      "name": "Mimi Keel",
      "id": 243,
      "city": "London",
      "country": "UK",
      "tags": ["portrait", "events", "travel", "animals"],
      "tagline": "Voir le beau dans le quotidien",
      "price": 400,
      "portrait": "MimiKeel.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ellie-Rose Wilkens",
      "id": 930,
      "city": "Paris",
      "country": "France",
      "tags": ["sports", "architecture"],
      "tagline": "Capturer des compositions complexes",
      "price": 250,
      "portrait": "EllieRoseWilkens.jpg"
    }
  ],
```

I am trying to loop trough the array contained in the key `tags` in the first `photographers` entry and display the all tags in a list item.

Heres what i got so far:

```
function fetchData() {
  fetch("sample json file.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data.photographers[0].tags[1])

      // looping throw tags of a photographer
      var output = "";

      for (var i = 0; i <= data.photographers[0].tags.length; i++) {
        for (keys in data.photographers[0].tags[i]) {
          console.log(data.photographers[0].tags[i])
          if (data.photographers[0].tags[i].hasOwnProperty(keys)) {
            output += '<li>' +
              '<a href="' + data.photographers[0].tags[i] +
              '">' + data.photographers[0].tags[i] + '</a>' +
              '</li>';
          }
        }
      }
      var update = document.getElementById('tags');

      update.innerHTML = output;
    })
}

fetchData();
```

I am open to any suggestion or correction of my code

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: are you asking for refactor ? cause it's the wrong Stack for this: on a side note, you can replace ` data.photographers[0].tags[i]` with `key` in your second loop.

Comment: Don't iterate arrays with `for .. in`, use proper array methods or `for .. of` instead.

Comment: when i try to loop throug the tags and display them in duplicates it several time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop can be made really simple. It has a couple of issues such as the one you mentioned, and another is dealing with multiple photographers and not just the first (Not sure if this is your actual use case):

Your code change: Remove your inner for loop as that's what duplicates everything:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < data.photographers[0].tags.length; i++) {
  console.log(data.photographers[0].tags[i])
}
```

Suggestion:

```js
// same data given in the question
let data = { "photographers": [{ "name": "Mimi Keel","id": 243,"city": "London","country": "UK","tags": ["portrait", "events", "travel", "animals"],"tagline": "Voir le beau dans le quotidien","price": 400,"portrait": "MimiKeel.jpg" }, {"name": "Ellie-Rose Wilkens","id": 930,"city": "Paris","country": "France","tags": ["sports", "architecture"],"tagline": "Capturer des compositions complexes","price": 250,"portrait": "EllieRoseWilkens.jpg"  }]};

// All photographers
for (let photographer of data.photographers) {
  for (let tag of photographer.tags) {
    console.log(tag);
    // Here you get individual tag. Use it in your code like generating output.
  }
}

// Just the first photographer
for (let tag of data.photographers[0].tags) {
  console.log(tag);
  // Here you get individual tag. Use it in your code like generating output.
}
```

Comment: fine, please now how can i do to dispplay all the tags in <li><a></a></li> in the DOM ?

Comment: Keep a section like <div id="output"></div>. In javascript you can have a variable before loop like var list = ""; And inside the loop, you can create list element like: list += ``<li><a href="http://www.google.com/${tag}">${tag}</a></li>``; Finally outside the loop: document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = list;

Comment: Inside the loop, remember to use the backtick symbol instead of double/single quotes. Here's an example - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals